# GWT/ JSP- how to run jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, gwt

I am on a project that uses GWT/ eclipse/ SQL Developer and the guy who originally implemented it is no longer on the project. We have a normal WAR and everything but the jsp files are kept in a different environment. Anyone know why? Can they not be run through GWT?

The issue we are facing is the only way we have to test/ compile JSPs is to actually deploy it into DEV which takes a lot of time. So we are in need of being able to run JSPs locally.

I have been told someone used to use Jdeveloper to do this, but I am unfamiliar with it and the only YouTube tutorials are in a foreign language (in regards to using JSPs with JDeveloper 11g). Someone else suggested notepad/ Tomcat? Or yet another option would be to configure eclipse to run it with our current project in GWT?

I am not familiar with any of this being I am brand new to JSPs,Tomcat, etc. and am in desperate need of some help.

What is the best way to accomplish my needs and are there any guides/ tutorials to help me through the process?

My requirements are just to run a folder with 4 linked jsps and be able to connect to the database to provide the information.

Comment: Have you installed the [GWT plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download)?

Comment: yes, the plugin is necessary for our java development which i am much more familiar with.

Comment: My only experience is with Google App engine which runs JSPs and can be deployed locally.

Comment: After reading your question(s), I fear your best option is to hire an experienced consultant... (this is not an offense)

Comment: while an experienced consultant would be nice, it is not necessary as we can currently complete all requirements and we rarely work with any jsps. I have worked here for almost a year and this is the first time i needed to do work on a jsp. We normally do only java code and everything works great in that aspect.

Comment: Can you elaborate on google app engine? Would it accomplish my needs?

Comment: @TheJavaBeast: then you just need a local servlet engine, e.g. Tomcat or (maybe better) Jetty, latter is built into the Eclipse GWT plugin. Btw: Google App Engine is 'cloud' - a different story.

Comment: jsp uses EclipseEE GWT just uses plain eclipse like a helios release

Answer (score 0):

> "I am not familiar with any of this being I am brand new to
>   JSPs,Tomcat, etc. and am in desperate need of some help."

That's sounds true!

One answer about the different environments is that jsp needs "EE" .I.E. EclipseEE but the GWT app just uses plain old eclipse (like an eclipse helios release with GWT plugin).

Regarding your requirements, I can't understand them clearly enough to begin to provide helpful information, but good luck.

Tony